# GIT with WAMP setup

Tags: eclipse, git, apache, wamp

I have setup Eclipse with PDT and EGIT in an effort to start focusing on better practices for version control and to help with syntax highlighting. I am running windows 7. I was able to load my php projects and work with EGIT on my development system but I want to have a central repo on my server where I can grab files from and push files to. I am kind of new to GIT, so I am not sure how to do this. I have found tutorials talking about SSH to do this but I am not familiar with this.

SO my question is how can I setup something on my server with all of my website projects (IE wamp/www) where I can pull and push files from Eclipse on a development machine. Any tutorials with these steps that work with Windows 7 will help. I have looked at a bunch of tutorials but it seems to cross between linux and windows and gets confusing. Or are there better alternatives to GIT for a windows environment?

Comment: Your question is vague, broad, and asking for opinions.  Try narrowing it down to getting help with a specific setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best Git server on Windows remains [**Bonobo Git Server**](http://bonobogitserver.com/).
It allows for [hosting Git repos](http://bonobogitserver.com/features/), with access control level, and you will be able to clone/pull from those repos, or push to them.

It uses however [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) as a server, not Wamp.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Was extremely easy to setup versus the git ssh nightmare I was messing with. I use reverse proxy in apache already for some asp.net websites so IIS was not an issue for setting it up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To start off with - you don't need a server to push and pull.

git is decentralized. This means you don't really need a server, because all clients have the completely repository. The server would just be another backup and (depending on the server you decide to use) provide a nice GUI for browsing the repositories.

A server does come in handy if you are dealing with multiple developers or you want to have a place to track bugs and store other "meta" information about your project.

If you are looking for a central server for git *and you must deploy it on Windows*, I would just go with @VonC's suggestion.

If you don't need the server to be locally hosted, [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) provides both git and mercurial hosting, and with their free account you can have private repositories. A great option if you are just starting out because you don't want to have to deal with the headache of maintaining another server. They also provide an excellent Windows git client for free, called [sourcetree](http://sourcetreeapp.com)

If you are able to spin up a linux virtual machine, then [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) is an excellent option. The [free community edition](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) is what you would want. [Rhodecode](https://rhodecode.com/) is another option as well.

Again, I would really question the wisdom of managing your own git repository server - is it really worth the headache?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I went with VonC's answer with this. It was really easy to set up.